# Как передать ключ объекта в функцию?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, функции, объекты

Мне нужно передать ключ из объекта в функцию, но получается что этот ключ `undefined`.
Каким образом я получаю `error`: Данный объект получаю из props (with Redux), изначально `error: ''`, но если при срабатывании функции `catch` улавливает ошибку то уже `error: {code: 'code error', message: 'message error'}`

Есть у меня вот такая `thunk` :

error - тот один из ключей и его значения объекта

```
export const loginInWithEmail = (email, password,error) => (dispatch) => {
    if(error !== String){dispatch(loadingAuth(true))}
    fire.auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => dispatch(loadingAuth(false)))
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch(getError(error));
        });
};
```

А вот сама компонента:

```
const UserComponent = ({error}) => {
    // когда устанавливаю console.log(error.code) здесь все работает и оно === 'код ошибки'
    const loginIn = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        loginInWithEmail(email, password,error.code); // когда устанавливаю console.log(error.code) здесь то === 'undefined'
    };
  return(
    //code
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ваша операция асинхронная, воспользуйтесь [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) или [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
const UserComponent = ({ error }) => {
    const loginIn = async e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        await loginInWithEmail(email, password, error.code)
        console.log(error.code)
    }
  return // ... то что возвращаете
}
```

либо проблема в action'e `getError(error)`, стоит добавить его код в Ваш вопрос.